# Thinkpad T460p Ultra Dock HDMI no audio

Tags: sound, hdmi, monitor, thinkpad

I recently purchased a ThinkPad T460p and installed Ubuntu 16.04LTS on it.

The docking station I use is the ThinkPad Ultra Dock.

If I hook up my Iiyama XB2888HS Monitor (w/speakers) via an HDMI cable directly to the side port of the laptop, everything works fine.

However, if I hook it up via the docking station, this results in no audio being heard.

Looking at the System Settings > Sound > Output, I see that while the the monitor is hooked up on the side, the HDMI appears in the list, but when using the docking station, I only see the PC Speakers and no HDMI.

Is this a known problem and is there any way to fix it?

Thanks in advance for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a known [bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1101386#c31) the solution seems to be adding an option in modrprobe.d

```
echo "options snd-hda-intel model=tpt460" > /etc/modprobe.d/alsadock.conf
```

Comment: You probably want to use `>>` in order not to nuke things.

Comment: This didn't work. Do I also need to install a driver patch?